Illegal mix of collations Error In MariaDB Procedure
I am struggling with a stored procedure in MariaDB:
CREATE DEFINER=`User`@`%` PROCEDURE `MYTABLE`(IN mytable_id VARCHAR(36))
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM mytables WHERE recordid = mytable_id;
END

The following query results in an error:
CALL MYTABLE("062ede33-xxxx-41eb-xxxx-77c776666016")

The Error:
1267 - Illegal mix of collations (utf8mb4_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8mb4_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '='

Verified 100% that the collation on the recordid column has the utf8mb4_general_ci collation.
Not sure what is going on here. Can someone please explain why I am getting this error and possible how to fix it?

I was unable to reproduce this on 10.6.19. Can you include show create procedure MYTABLE\G and the \s on your connection for current collation information when doing the call?

collation_connection is utf8mb4_general_ci

Me too. What MariaDB version? This might be a fixed bug. What's the full show create procedure MYTABLE\G output as there's a default charset/collation information there.

10.6.18.  Everything is where it needs to be.  character_set_client is utf8mb4.  database_collation is utf8mb4_general_ci collation_connection is 'utf8mb4_general_ci'

Oddly enough if I turn it into a parametized query and prepare/execute it, it works fine.

Specify correct collation explicitly: .. WHERE recordid = mytable_id COLLATE utf8mb4_general_ci;, for example.

Have you checked the parameter collation in information_schema.PARAMETERS ?

Also, please provide `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "coll%';

When a procedure is created, the procedure definition stores the database's character set and collation that are in effect at the time of creation (unless specified in the parameter definitions).
You can check the collation settings in the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES table.
To resolve the issue, recreate the procedure so that it inherits the current collation settings.
